# Is it possible to invoke NSDictionary's valueForKeyPath: when a key contains periods?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, foundation

I'm trying to get the value of the repeatInterval key in the com.apple.scheduler plist. I'd like to just use NSDictionary's valueForKeyPath: method like so:

```
CFPropertyListRef value;
value = CFPreferencesCopyValue(CFSTR("AbsoluteSchedule"),
                               CFSTR("com.apple.scheduler"),
                               kCFPreferencesCurrentUser,
                               kCFPreferencesCurrentHost);
NSNumber *repeatInterval = [(NSDictionary *)value valueForKeyPath:@"com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.SUCheckSchedulerTag.Timer.repeatInterval"];
```

But the problem with this is that the first key is really "com.apple.SoftwareUpdate", not just "com". I can get around this by getting that first value separately:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [(NSDictionary *)value valueForKey:@"com.apple.SoftwareUpdate"];
NSNumber *repeatInterval = [dict valueForKeyPath:@"SUCheckSchedulerTag.Timer.repeatInterval"];
```

I just wanted to know if there is a way to escape periods in a keypath so I can eliminate this extra step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSDictionary doesn't have a valueforKeyPath: method.  It just invokes the NSObject implementation which is the root of your problem.

Maybe you could reimplement it in a category on NSDictionary with your own escape characters.

Comment: I don't think I'll encounter this issue often enough to justify writing a category for it, so I'll just stick with the extra line of code for now. Thanks for the clarification.